# Dynamic Filtering of ArrayList with another ArrayList Java 8

Tags: filter, java-8

I have a few Search Results Objects as given below:

```
public class TradeSearchResult{ 

    private String tradeRefNo;
    private String relatedTradeId;
    private String custodyDate;
    private String orderNumber;
    private String odrQty;
    private String price : 500;
}

public class CollateralTradesSearchResult{

    private String excludeTradeOUT;
    private String settlementStatus;
    private String fundId;
    private String altFundId;
    private String apNumber;
    private String collateralOrderNumber;
    private String componenetIdentifier;
}
```

Now I have a Search Filter Criteria object

```
public class CRITERION {  

    protected String field; //The field denotes any field name of the either 
                              SearchResult object
    protected String operator; its will be EQUALS or NOT_EQUALS   
    protected String value; Value of the field.
}
```

Now I need to write a Dynamic Filter Method where I will pass the List of Criterion object and can pass List of either SearchResult like below

```
public static List<Object> applyFilter(List<CRITERION> comp, List<?> objectList){

    //The CRITERION.fiedName can be same in more than one in the list 
    return filteredList;

}
```

here is one example: Consider the below List of

```
TradeSearchResult{
 tradeRefNo : W12343;
 relatedTradeId: N993093;
 custodyDate : 2018-12-14;
 orderNumber : 0000342343;
 String odrQty : 12;
 String price : 500;
},
{
 tradeRefNo : W12344;
 relatedTradeId: N993093;
 custodyDate : 2018-12-14;
 orderNumber : 0000342344;
 String odrQty : 18;
 String price : 600;

},
{
  tradeRefNo : W12345;
 relatedTradeId: N993094;
 custodyDate : 2018-12-14;
 orderNumber : 0000342345;
 String odrQty : 20;
 String price : 700;
}

Now the Criterion class is like 
CRITERION{

    field :relatedTradeId; 
    operator : EQUALS;    
    value :N993093;
}
{    
    field :relatedTradeId; 
    operator : EQUALS;    
    value :N993094;    
}
{    
    field :orderNumber ; 
    operator : EQUALS;    
    value :0000342344;

}
```

It will only return one result even relatedTradeId has two filter

```
TradeSearchResult{
 tradeRefNo : W12344;
 relatedTradeId: N993093;
 custodyDate : 2018-12-14;
 orderNumber : 0000342344;
 String odrQty : 18;
 String price : 600;
}
```

Now in the same applyFIlter Method I can send a list of Criterion and a list of CollateralTradesSearchResult and returns filtered result.
Here is something I tried

```
public static List<Object> applyFilter(List<CRITERION> criList, List<?> objectList){    
    long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();          
        Set<Object> objectSet = new HashSet<>();    

        for(CRITERION cri : criList){
        String fieldName = cri.getFIELD();
        objectList.stream().filter(p->beanProperties(p).get(fieldName).equals(cri.getVALUE())).forEachOrdered(objectSet::add);
        //objectList.retainAll(objectSet);
        //objectSet.clear();
        }

        List<Object> ret =  new ArrayList<>(objectSet);
        long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("Size"+ ret.size());
        System.out.println("Time Taken to Search"+ String.valueOf(endTime-startTime));
    return ret;
    }
```

Hereis the beanProperties() method

```
public static Map<String, Object> beanProperties(Object bean) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            Arrays.asList(Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass(), Object.class)
                                      .getPropertyDescriptors())
                  .stream()
                  // filter out properties with setters only
                  .filter(pd -> Objects.nonNull(pd.getReadMethod()))
                  .forEach(pd -> { // invoke method to get value
                      try {
                          Object value = pd.getReadMethod().invoke(bean);
                          if (value != null) {
                              map.put(pd.getName(), value);
                          }
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          // add proper error handling here
                      }
                  });
            return map;
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            // and here, too
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    }
Any help using Stream or by any means will be helpful.
```

Comment: You are asking us to write all that code for you? That's not how SO works. Please provide what (code) you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface `SearchResult` and make both your classes implement it. Then create this class:

```
public class Filter<T extends SearchResult> {

    public List<T> applyFilter(List<Criterion> criteria, List<T> list) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> allowedValues = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Set<String>> prohibitedValues = new HashMap<>();
        populateValues(criteria, "EQUALS", allowedValues);
        populateValues(criteria, "NOT_EQUALS", prohibitedValues);

        prohibitedValues.forEach((k, v) -> list.removeIf(t -> v.contains(getFieldValue(k, t))));
        allowedValues.forEach((k, v) -> list.removeIf(t -> !v.contains(getFieldValue(k, t))));
        return list;
    }

    private static void populateValues(List<Criterion> criteria, String operator, Map<String, Set<String>> values) {
        criteria.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getOperator().equals(operator))
                .forEach(c -> {
                    values.merge(c.getField(), Stream.of(c.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toSet()),
                            (set1, set2) -> Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                });
    }

    private String getFieldValue(String fieldName, T object) {
        Field field;
        try {
            field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            return (String) field.get(object);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```
Filter<TradeSearchResult> filter = new Filter<>(); //or CollateralTradesSearchResult
List<TradeSearchResult> filteredList = filter.applyFilter(criteria, searchResults);
```